# Log into Wordpress by Moodle DB

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, external, moodle, password-encryption

I deploy Wordpress(Version 3.5.1) and Moodle(V 2.5+) at my PC.

And i install the Wrodpress plugin [External DB authentication](http://wordpress.org/plugins/external-database-authentication/) to make the Moodle DB's user could be able to log into Wordpress **instead of** creating new account in Wordpress.

I choose the default **MD5 password encryption method** in plugin configration.Is it wrong?

I also researsh the solution [How to Authenticate Users From Moodle Into WordPress MU](http://jasontbedell.com/how-to-authenticate-users-from-moodle-into-wordpress-mu), which it can find easily by Google. Unfortunately, it doesn't work well. And i couldn't find the Moodle **password encrytion(or the salt code)** method in Moodle source code. I'm thinking if the two different password encryption/authentication methods make this issue.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

See this http://blog.giuseppeurso.net/moodle-and-wordpress-single-sign-on-in-20-minutes-part-1/index.html

Use extrenal database in moodle

Answer (score 0):

in moodle use this auth plugin: https://github.com/frumbert/wp2moodle-moodle

in wordpress use this plugin: https://github.com/frumbert/wp2moodle--wordpress-

Iḿ using in my moodle 2.5 and wordpress 3.5.2